# Can I create 2-level structure of modules in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, architecture

I have 3 gradle projects. But each of them consists of 10 gradle subprojects. May I merge it to one big gradle project with 3 big modules, and every module with 10 gradle subprojects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you need it. The only thing is, that you can have only one `settings.gradle` file in your root project, where you have to include all the subprojects with their relative paths, like:

```
include "subProject", "subProject:subSubProject"
```

This will make a project structure like:

```
Root project
├── settings.gradle
├── Sub project
|   ├── Sub-sub project
|   |   └── build.gradle
|   └── build.gradle
└── build.gradle
```